# generators of a prime ideal in a noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $P$ is a prime ideal. If the number of generators of $PR_P$ as an ideal in $R_P$ is $n$, can we say anything about the number of generators of $P$ as an ideal of $R$?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  You're welcome to ask those there, but you ought to review http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question .

Comment: @Dimitrije Kostic: What made you think this is a HW problem? It is not, and from the several google searches I did, I don't think it has a straightforward answer either.

Comment: The homework problems that show up around here tend to be tersely stated, as your question is.  Sorry if I was mistaken.

Comment: You can deduce that there exists $f \in R \setminus P$ such that the ideal $PR_f$ is generated by $n$ elements, as ideal of $R_f$. But it might be the case that you cannot choose $f = 1$, i.e. $P$ may not be generated by $n$ elements as ideal of $R$. For example, take $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $P = (2, 1+ \sqrt{-5})$: $P$ is not principal but $P R_P$ is principal.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly $P$ has at least $n$ generators, as the images of the generators in $R_p$ generate $PR_p$. As you can see from Andrea's comment, the we cannot give an upper bound in general. This is because the number of generators is not really a "nice" property of ideals. A closely related property is the [height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_%28ring_theory%29) of an ideal, which for a prime ideal $P$ is the supremum of the lengths of chains of prime ideals contained in $P$, and for a general ideal is the infimum of the heights of prime ideals containing it. Since we have a bijection between the ideals of $R$ contained in $P$ and the ideals of $R_P$, the height of $P$ is the same as the height of $PR_P$. While this is not quite what you're looking for, it's close. By the [generalized principal ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem), the height of an ideal in a Noetherian ring is at most the number of generators. In some cases we can say more, especially for prime ideals. For example, prime ideals of height $1$ in a UFD have exactly one generator. In a regular local ring, the height of the maximal ideal is equal to its number of generators.